# Rails Migration failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Hello I have a model called tools

on this model, i have previously added a reference to tool type

```
add_reference :tools, :tool_type, null: false, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
```

I now want to change this to remove the null false while i expand some other models.

I created a migration

```
class RemoveNullFromToolType < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :tools, :tool_type, null: true
  end
end
```

but it fails with the below

```
-- change_column(:tools, :tool_type, {:null=>true})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for {:null=>true}:Hash
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_set
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Eyeslandic get the same error

Comment: did you setup `UUID` type ?

Comment: Check the documentation for [`change_column_null`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_null) and [`change_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column), you have the arguments wrong.